# Trying to build custom electronics connection to a motorized zoom/focus lens

Tags: camera, optics, hacking, fpc

I'm a beginner when it comes to electronics, I had some success with pretty simple arduino based projects like blue tooth controlled stepper motor assemblies using well documented drivers and components from places like adafruit.

What I'd like to do is to connect custom electronics to a motorized device like a zoom/focus lens found in many digital cameras. I took the plunge and purchased a Sony DSC-H90 replacement lens which is intended for people to plug in to a Sony camera motherboard if their lens assembly is broken.
[image: Sony DSC-h90 lens replacement]

However, I'm wondering if it is possible to connect to the flexible ribbon coming off of the camera and send and receive along the individual pins.

I was able to download the service manual for this lens assembly and it seems to provide some idea as to what each pin is supposed to do - I'm guessing with some trial and error one could design appropriate stepper motor drivers for example to run the inner stepper motors that control zoom and focus - maybe even to listen to the sensors that indicate home position for the motors.

Given my inexperience this is a big goal for me but I know I'd learn a lot along the way. I'm embarrassed to say however that I'm stuck on step 1 - I can't figure out what kind of FPC ribbon I'm dealing with.
[image: odd fpc cable]

The width of the conductor strands of this ribbon varies, some are thick, some are thin. I count 35 pins, but it seems that the pitch of this connector is not uniform. How do you connect to a ribbon like this? Is this something that Sony does on purpose to make it more difficult for people like me to connect directly to the electronics assembly?

I may be missing something obvious as to why what I'm trying to do is not possible, I'd love to get any feedback that more experienced may be willing to share. Perhaps some replacement motorized lenses are going to be an easier project than this one given the strange ribbon at then end!

Thanks all in advance

Comment: Yeah that right there looks proprietary.  Cost equal to cost of broken camera I'd guess.  Have you considered doing a project with a camera with known control mechanisms, or do you have experience with reverse engineering?  This is not a beginner level project.  It's advanced enough you might achieve it faster by starting off with easier projects to increase your learning rate until you're ready for this one.  That said, obtaining a broken rest-of-the-camera's-guts might be necessary to figure out how to safely drive the motors.

Comment: `pitch of this connector is not uniform` ... look again ... some of the pins are connected in pairs

Comment: @jstola thank you for the response. I didn't realize that pins could be connected in pairs but that makes total sense - it's then 45 total pins which is what the service manual indicates, and I think then the pitch is 0.3mm. When an fpc has pins connected in pairs do you need a special FPC connector, or would a 0.3mm 45 pin connector work? I found also that the main motor moving the lens in and out is a 4.5 V DC motor, Thanks again, at least I feel like I have a next step:)

Comment: why would you need a special connector if adjacent pins are connected to the same wire? ... it happens all the time with ICs and connectors

Comment: @jsotola thanks again, you really taught me something today that in retrospect is so obvious. Now looking at the service diagram electrical schematic, it is absolutely clear that pins are wired to each other, and it's all matching up perfectly. Once I get my 45 pin 0.3mm connector (on a breakout board since my soldering skills are nowhere near the level needed to solder 45 pins myself), I think that i'll be able to get some of these motors moving!